# Are the epochs equivalent to the iterations?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I'm testing a multilayer perceptron with both scikit-learn and keras using the tensorflow backend.

Keras: epochs=X
Scikit:  max_iter=X

The epochs of keras are the same as the iterations of scikit learn???

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have no experience with SciKit Learn, however, in deep learning terminology an "iteration" is a gradient update step, while an epoch is a pass over the entire dataset. For example, if I have 1000 data points and am using a batch size of 100, every 10 iterations is a new epoch. See [Epoch vs iteration when training neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752626/epoch-vs-iteration-when-training-neural-networks).

Answer (score 4):

Although [the other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/284494/9964) is correct for the standard terminology, unfortunately scikit-learn uses non-standard terms here, as can be seen [from the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L508-L521): `sklearn.neural_network.MLP{Classifier,Regressor}` use `max_iters` to refer to the number of epochs. The [relevant lines](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L508-L521) look essentially like:

```
for it in range(self.max_iter):
    X, y = shuffle(X, y)
    for batch in gen_batches(n_samples, batch_size):
        # compute gradients on batch
        # take a step along that gradient

    # check stopping criterion
```

where [the `gen_batches` helper](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/utils/__init__.py#L316-L338) splits up the whole dataset.

I sent [a pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9089) clarifying this as a result of this question; the docs are now clearer, so thanks for asking!